# Is there a way to restore my Samsung Galaxy S3 (SCH-i747)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, unbricking

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (SCH-I747) that I tried to root using [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQL9fVSisFI)

Somehow something went horribly, horrible wrong and now I think I have hard bricked it.

My symptoms:

- Phone does not turn on when you hold down the power button
- Cannot get into boot loader / download mode (screen is always black)
- My phone is now named "QHSUSB_DLOAD" in my explorer window

I obviously used odin to try to flash it and it didn't work. Will a [JIG](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/need-a-samsung-usb-jig-build-your-own/) get me into download screen? At this point I just want to be able to restore the original build.

Is there anyway (besides sending it in and paying $60) to fix my phone? I have the file I need to flash a build, can someone please help me get back into boot loader / download mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the same boat man..all my research has led me to needing to jtag.  I ordered the download jig, new battery and charger.  Tried on several systems including xp to no avail.  I'll be sending it into Mobiletechrepairs on account of I'm sending in an old phone to cover the cost so I might be out of pocket for shipping.  Wish I was able to find someone local but most phone repair shops don't know what jtag is!  I'll let you know the turn around time and what condition my phone gets returned in.  Good luck.

Comment: Please note: This is not a discussion forum. If you're not offering a solution to the original question, _don't_ use the Answer space. I suggest you check out our [about] page and [FAQ] to learn how this site is different than others you may be used to.

Answer (score 0):

If you bricked it with a simple bad bootloader/modem flash you can use the method outlined here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2660566 and see if it works for you, I've had it work on a bunch of phones that I've recommended its use on.

Download the image that corresponds to your phone from here:  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B612qYHFMILfWUlMTTEwdUstcXM?usp=sharing
then use a disk imager to "burn" the image to a 16 or 32gb class 10 sd card. Remove the battery on the phone, put the sd card in and then reinsert the battery. Press the power button until you feel vibration (this may take upwards of 15 seconds) and then either it will boot normally, or you will need to boot into odin mode and flash a stock image

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on this site, if the link goes dead, your answer is worthless. Please, at least outline the method in your answer.

Comment: My apologies, I will gather the links necessary, the ones I uploaded to google drive for that link and post them along with the full guide